# How to get the source IP field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community, dynamic-visualforce

we want to get the source IP field from login history object. We do not know how to get it. We can get the IP but the system randomly chooses a one. Does anybody have any idea? thanks

```
trigger ProductBriefHistory on Product_Brief__c (after update) {
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> trackedFields = SObjectType.Product_Brief__c.FieldSets.PBHistoryTracking.getFields();
if (trackedFields.isEmpty()) return;


LoginHistory src = [SELECT SourceIp from LoginHistory WHERE UserId =:UserInfo.getUserId() Limit 1];

 List<Product_Brief_History__c> fieldChanges = new List<Product_Brief_History__c>();

 List<string> apiNameList = new List<string>();        

if(Trigger.isUpdate){
for (Product_Brief__c aNew : trigger.new) {

Product_Brief__c aOld = trigger.oldmap.get(aNew.Id);

for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : trackedFields) {

 String fieldName  = fsm.getFieldPath();
String fieldLabel = fsm.getLabel();

if (aNew.get(fieldName) != aOld.get(fieldName)) {

String oldValue = String.valueOf(aOld.get(fieldName));
String newValue = String.valueOf(aNew.get(fieldName));
if (oldValue != null && oldValue.length()>255) oldValue = oldValue.substring(0,255);
 if (newValue != null && newValue.length()>255) newValue = newValue.substring(0,255); 

 Product_Brief_History__c aht = new Product_Brief_History__c();
    aht.Product_Brief__c = aNew.Id;
aht.name__c         = fieldLabel;
aht.apiName__c   = fieldName;

aht.Updated_By__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
aht.OldValue__c  = oldValue;
 aht.NewValue__c  = newValue;
    aht.Source_IP__c = src.SourceIp;


 apiNameList.add(aht.apiName__c);
 fieldChanges.add(aht);
}        
}
}
}
if (!fieldChanges.isEmpty()) {
 insert fieldChanges;
 }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the system randomly chooses one?" How do you know this? Do you have anything to back it up?

Comment: It does not give the latest Ip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem with your code is that `LoginHistory` can have many entries per `UserId` but your query of `LoginHistory` does not define the order and so does not define which entry you get.

If you want the latest entry then you need e.g.:

```
LoginHistory src = [
        select SourceIp
        from LoginHistory
        where UserId =:UserInfo.getUserId()
        order by LoginTime desc
        limit 1
        ];
```